# transfer a function as a parameter to a different function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to transfer a function as a parameter to a different function.

for some reason it is not working.

```
//myClass.h
class MyClass
{
public:

typedef int (*MyClass::ptrToMember)(float, char);

  ptrToMember p1;
  MyClass::MyClass();
  void hello(ptrToMember fun);

  int SendIt (float a, char b); 

};



//MyClass.cpp
MyClass::MyClass(){
  p1 = &(MyClass::SendIt);
  hello(p1);

}
int MyClass::SendIt (float a, char b) 
{ 
  std::cout << "MyClass::SendIt "<<a<<std::endl; 

  return 1; 
}

void MyClass::hello(ptrToMember fun){

 int result = (*fun)(12, 'a');
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

would appreciate it, if someone can tell me what my mistake is.

Comment: You're confusing functions and member functions.

Comment: it has a problem with this line:p1 = &(MyClass::SendIt);

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but pretty much any time you want to use function pointers in C++, using a polymorphic class with a virtual function is a safer, cleaner solution. That's only an opinion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef int (*MyClass::ptrToMember)(float, char);
             ^
// your mistake is here
```

Pointers to class member functions are declared like this:

```
typedef int (MyClass::*ptrToMember)(float, char);
                      ^
```

And called like this (test is the class instance - can also be 'this'):

```
 (test.*pointer)(parameters) // if test is automatically allocated
```

or

```
 (test->*pointer)(parameters) // if test is a pointer
```

The decleration operator is `::*`, while the operator to invoke your pointer to a member function are `.*` and `->*`.

**Edit:**

This line:

```
p1 = &(MyClass::SendIt);
```

actually has to be:

```
p1 = &MyClass::SendIt; // without parentheses
```

Comment: thanks.. i still get an error (Error 1 error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression c:\cpp\functionpointer\a.cpp 7
) on the line p1 = &(MyClass::SendIt);

Comment: Updated, btw, what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Say this:

```
typedef int (MyClass::*ptrToMember)(float, char);

// ...

int result = (this->*fun)(12, 'a');
```